# Angular's post request is blocked by the server due to cors policy but is working fine with Postman

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data, http-status-code-500

On front-end I am using Angular 14, Back-end is of Asp.net Core v5.

In asp.net core I have disabled the cors by adding

```
AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
```

Now my other forms are working fine.

But, this form where I am using Form Data is creating an issue. Let see the browser
[image]

Another error below this is
[image]

Now it  says its a cors issue. However let me remind us all that I have already added the cors policy and all my other form is working fine.

So in addition to this request, I have added one more header and now my http packet looks like this,
[image]

I have added the missing header as well but the result is the same. What could have gone wrong?

Is the formdata culprit? or is the file?

on the server side, I have added the cors policy
[image]

and this is my ViewModel

[image]

Additionaly this is the action method

[image]

Comment: did you set correct content type "multipart/form-data;" although it is complaining about cors but seems content type is not set properly.

Comment: CORS headers should be on the response, not request. the issue is in ASP.net configuration 100%

Comment: @Andrei The problem got solved after I cleared my browser cache. I think initially it was the formdata mistake which was cached as all my asp.net controller are made in the same way

Comment: @CodingMytra I think you're right. The problem could  have been due to  the wrong form data setup as some fields were missing. So I rebuilt every formdata, cleared the cache (which was the important step) and then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem and it was not related to CORS policy as such.

The problem was "Model Validation"

I have not mentioned the extra file field which was going to the server in the server's View model.

Later on, I added another property of type "IFormFile?" which would successfully receive the file data from my FormData.